How can one unselect a post that was selected with a keyboard shortcut without selecting another post or reloading/changing the page?
How can one unselect a post that has been selected with a keyboard shortcut without selecting another one or reloading/changing the page?


Example of a selected a post, which is indicated by a grey fade.
The post was selected with the keyboard shortcut E then Cancel.


@Makyen If you know  a way to select a post without using a keyboard shortcut, can you please an answer on Is editing a post the only way to select a post?

Frank, the issue is you're using a specialized concept of what "select a post" means that's inherently, and only, part of the site-specific keyboard shortcuts SE provides as an optional UI interaction method. There are at least a couple of other concepts as to what "select a post" could mean, even if just exclusively talking about question pages. What you've really meant by "select a post" here and in your linked question is more accurately something like "on a question page, cause a post to be recognized as 'selected' within SE's optional keyboard shortcuts".

Not possible by default
The keyboard shortcuts only allow you to change selection once there is one. Reloading is the only way to stop having a selected post.

Possible with some custom code
To remove the selection it is enough to remove the "keyboard-selected" class. The following jQuery code will achieve that:
$(".keyboard-selected").removeClass("keyboard-selected")

This can be converted to a bookmarklet:
javascript:(function()%7B%24(%22.keyboard-selected%22).removeClass(%22keyboard-selected%22)%7D)()

To add it to your browser see How to Create Bookmarklets
This could also be incorporated into a userscript or a browser extension (for example, it could be executed when pressing a key).
